# System.Plugins loader seems to assume failure after seeing a failure once

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, interpreter, dynamic-compilation

I am currently working on a haskell program which takes a users input from a text box, then
compiles and loads it using the [System.Plugins](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins-1.5.1.4) library in order to extract a picture to draw to the screen. The user can edit the code in the text box, then reload their new image by clicking a compile button. Here is the code which is fired when the compile button is clicked:

```
compileText :: SourceView -> SOE.Window -> IO ()
compileText tview w = do 
    txtBuff <- textViewGetBuffer tview
    startIt <- textBufferGetStartIter txtBuff
    endIt <- textBufferGetEndIter txtBuff
    compTime <- getClockTime
    srcString <- textBufferGetByteString txtBuff startIt endIt False

    BS.writeFile "Test.hs" srcString
    mkStat <- make "Test.hs" []
    case mkStat of
        MakeSuccess cd fp -> print fp
        MakeFailure (er1:er2:errs) -> error er2

    loadResult <- getModule
    case loadResult of
        Right (md, pic) -> do
                runGraphics $ do
                    draw3 "gtk test" pic w
                unload md
        Left errors -> print errors
    return ()

getModule :: IO (Either [String] (Module, Picture))
getModule = do 
               mv <- load "Test.o" ["."] [] "pic"
               case mv of
                    LoadFailure messages -> return (Left messages)
                    LoadSuccess x y -> return (Right (x, y))
```

And here is some example code that the user has entered into the text box:

```
module Test where
    import Picture

    r1,r2,r3,r4 :: Region
    r1 = Shape(Rectangle 2 1)
    r2 = Shape(Ellipse 2 1.5)
    r3 = Shape(RtTriangle 3 2)
    r4 = Shape(Polygon [(-2.5, 2.5), (-3.0,0), (-1.7,-1.0), (-1.1,0.2),(-1.5,2.0)])

    p1,p2,p3,p4 :: Picture
    p1 = Region Red r1
    p2 = Region Green r2
    p3 = Region Blue r3
    p4 = Region Yellow r4

    pics :: Picture
    pics = foldl Over EmptyPic [p1,p2,p3,p4]
```

This all works as intended provided the user writes code that correctly compiles and loads each time. When the user writes a piece of code which fails to load however (The example i have been playing with is changing 'pic' to 'pics' so that it cannot find the pic function to load) The intended behaviour is that the program will print the load error to the screen so that the user can presumably correct their code and try clicking the compile button again.

However, what actually happens is that once the program encounters a LoadFailure once, all subsequent attempts at clicking the compile button result in a load failure message, regardless of whether the code is correct or not!

I'm not really sure what is going on under the hood here, but it appears as if the program is keeping some memory of the previous result from evaluation to evaluation. How do I get the behaviour I am looking for?

**EDIT:** I have tried to isolate the problem by writing a small test case which illustrates the problem I am having without using gtk

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Time
import System.IO
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BSC

import System.Plugins.Make
import System.Plugins.Load
import System.Eval.Haskell

testCaseCorrect :: String
testCaseCorrect = "module Test where\n printGreeting :: String -> IO ()\n printGreeting greeting = print greeting"

-- This should cause load to fail as it will not be able to find the
-- printGreeting function
testCaseIncorrect :: String
testCaseIncorrect = "module Test where\n printGurting :: String -> IO ()\n printGurting greeting = print greeting"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    BS.writeFile "Test.hs" (BSC.pack testCaseCorrect)
    mkStat <- make "Test.hs" []

    case mkStat of
        MakeSuccess cd fp -> print fp
        MakeFailure (er1:er2:errs) -> error er2

    loadResult <- getModule
    case loadResult of
        Right (md, greeter) -> do
                greeter "Hi there"
                unload md
        Left errors -> print errors

    BS.writeFile "Test.hs" (BSC.pack testCaseIncorrect)

    mkStat2 <- make "Test.hs" []

    case mkStat2 of
        MakeSuccess cd fp -> print fp
        MakeFailure (er1:er2:errs) -> error er2

    loadResult2 <- getModule
    case loadResult2 of
        Right (md, greeter) -> do
                greeter "Hi there"
                unload md
        Left errors -> print errors


    BS.writeFile "Test.hs" (BSC.pack testCaseCorrect)
    mkStat3 <- make "Test.hs" []

    case mkStat3 of
        MakeSuccess cd fp -> print fp
        MakeFailure (er1:er2:errs) -> error er2

    loadResult3 <- getModule
    case loadResult3 of
        Right (md, greeter) -> do
                greeter "Hi there"
                unload md
        Left errors -> print errors

getModule :: IO (Either [String] (Module, String -> IO()))
getModule = do 
               mv <- load "Test.o" ["."] [] "printGreeting"
               case mv of
                    LoadFailure messages -> return (Left messages)
                    LoadSuccess x y -> return (Right (x, y))
```

This code produces the result:

```
"Test.o"
"Hi there"
"Test.o"
["load: couldn't find symbol <<printGreeting>>"]
"Test.o"
["load: couldn't find symbol <<printGreeting>>"]
```

I.e it manages to replicate the error

**EDIT 2:** It seems on some runs of this exact same code It also produces the output:

```
"Test.o"
"Hi there"
"Test.o"
"Hi there"
"Test.o"
"Hi there"
```

But I think this may be due to the fact that the consecutive compiles are run so quickly together.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think you should be using `unload` after an error occurs.

Comment: @DonStewart I had suspected this might be where I am going wrong. However, how do I unload the module in the case of an error? If I get a load success, I am given a value for the module and the corresponding function, but If i get a load failure, I am merely given a list of errors. Do I have to somehow manually create a module?

Comment: Could you produce a standalone test case that shows the problem? (not using a GUI to invoke load). I can look at this after work.

Comment: @DonStewart Thanks. I have edited the question to include a small example which uses most of the code from the original function minus all the gtk stuff. Hopefully this is enough information to solve this mystery

Answer (score 1):

I replicated the problem using my [updated version of the plugins library](https://github.com/Changaco/haskell-plugins) and I isolated three causes.

Firstly, the [getModificationTime function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory/latest/doc/html/System-Directory.html#v%3agetModificationTime) used to check if a module needs to be recompiled has insufficient precision (seconds).

Secondly, GHC appears to make the same mistake.

Thirdly, as Don Stewart said, the module needs to be unloaded, which can't be easily done because the API doesn't give you a direct reference to it.

I fixed the third problem in my repository by automatically unloading the module when the symbol lookup fails. The right way to fix the other two is probably to patch upstream.